# How do I get response URI from a Jersey web response?

Tags: http, jersey, jersey-client

If I do:

```
    Response response = webTarget.request().get();
    URI redirectUri = response.getLocation();
```

response.getLocation() will be null if Jersey does not need to follow a redirect or automatically follows a redirect.

Only for manual, non automatic redirects will response.getLocation() be non-null.

How do I tell if the Jersey Response followed an automatic redirect? How do I get that URL?

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for debugging purposes, you could register the [LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html) with your client which should give you the request / response cycles.

> webTarget.register(new LoggingFilter())

If you need to know this in production I think you'll have to handle the redirects yourself. I might be wrong, but I can't see a way to get request history from the client (unless you tracked it yourself of course).

Hope this helps.

Will